# jquery next() returning nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I was trying to select everything between adjacent `<p>`'s, the number of "p" changes every time. And contents in between p tag-pairs could be nothing to anything. Some thing like this:

```
    <p><a href="x">...ABC...</a></p>

    <<<<<<<< Beginning of what I want >>>>>>>>

    <fieldset>...</fieldset>
    <font title="...">...</font>
    sometext without any tag<br>
    <a href="...">...</a>
    //[0..N] more tags

    <<<<<<<< End of what I want >>>>>>>>

    <p><a href="x+1">...ABC...</a></p>
    [0..N] more "p"'s with similar pattern ("p" with random url in "a")
```

Update:

I want to wrap those rogue codes (untagged text) into some div so that I can process them later. Like this:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="1">
        <p><a href="x">...ABC...</a></p>

    <! Beginning of what I want >

        <fieldset>...</fieldset>
        <font title="...">...</font>
        sometext without any tag<br>
        <a href="...">...</a>
        //[0..N] more tags

    <! End of what I want >
    </div>
    <div id="2">
        <p><a href="x+1">...ABC...</a></p>
    </div>
    <div id="3">
        //something or nothing
    </div>
    //something or nothing
</div>
```

In order to do that, I had to this code because there is some text without any tags around it:

```
    var ps = $("p:contains('ABC')");
    ps.each(function(){
        if(!($(this).next()[0])){
            return true;
        }
        var me = $(this);
        var pa = me.parent().contents();
        var nx = me.next("p:contains('ABC')"); //returns [] in this case
        var i0 = pa.index(me);
        var i1 = pa.index(nx);
        if (i1 > i0) {
            var elements = pa.slice(i0, i1);
            elements.each(function(){
                //Do something
            });
        }
    });
```

As marked in the code, the next() function would not return anything even if I change it to next("p"). But if I use me.next().next().next().next().next() I can select the next "p" tag. Why would this happen? How could I do it better?

Comment: Are you asking for the stuff between `<p>...</p>` or `<p>...</p>IWANTTHIS<p>...</p>`

Comment: the latter. the the first would be too easy, just $("p").innerHTML...

Comment: Kinda hard to do without classes or IDs.

Comment: To me it's like impossible... Been scratching my head for hours.

Comment: Is there any more to the HTML?

Comment: @ericcire please see my updated answer with updated fiddle.

Comment: You should have updated the post on the first time itself. Its like you are putting new question one by one.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was a small problem until I realized it's much more difficult. You know, that's what a noob is. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

You Should Use `.nextUntil("p")` for this purpose! because .next() only checks for the next element and nextUntil() searches until an associated element found!

Comment: Nah.. .nextUntil("p") was my first attempt and i returns a list but it would not include the untagged text which is actually quite important. I don't know why the server side did not put it in any tags.

Comment: can you please explain briefly in simple english what you want actually? :) then it will be easy for me to help you!

Comment: above fiddle gets the content of each p which contains ABC, is this you want? :)

Comment: I want these: <fieldset>...</fieldset>
<font title="...">...</font>
sometext without any tag<br>
<a href="...">...</a>
//[0..N] more tags

Comment: you want all the html in between two p tags?

Comment: woah man i got the idea, just testing whether it works! please wait for sometime!

Comment: hey BTW can i do that by replace? i can't figure out any solution for it!

Comment: hmm, it's closer. The thing is I don't know how many p there is....And I want to put it back where it was but wrapped... as in my updated post. Still some more steps to go..

Comment: you want only that text which is without tags?

Comment: Yes, exactly, except that I want to wrap in in the new div I created as well as everyone else...Oh I see, it's a child of body so I would not get it with $("p") selector. Let me create a new question for this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21216/discussion-between-aspiring-aqib-and-ericcire)

Answer (score 1):

After reading your question what i am getting is you want the content from `<p>` tag... whether it is content or html tags. If i am wrong please let me know...

I have created a demo fiddle please have a look. http://jsfiddle.net/dineshswami/YpYWY/1/

**Updated Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/dineshswami/YpYWY/3/

HTML:

```
<p><a href="x">...ABC...</a></p>


<fieldset>...</fieldset>
<font title="...">...</font>
sometext without any tag<br>
<a href="...">...</a>
//[0..N] more tags

<p><a href="x+1">...ABC...</a></p>
```

Jquery:

```
$("p").contents().unwrap();
```

Output:

```
<a href="x">...ABC...</a>


    <fieldset>...</fieldset>
    <font title="...">...</font>
    sometext without any tag<br>
    <a href="...">...</a>
    //[0..N] more tags

    <a href="x+1">...ABC...</a>
```

Comment: Well, no...What I want is the stuff between this <p></p> and the next <p></p>, in this case, <fieldset>, <font>, untagged text, <br>, <a> and etc, all of them. What's in the <p></p> tags will always be 'ABC'.

Comment: @ericcire Dear can you please specify clearly what exactly you want. In my code what ever in <p></p> tag it will put inside yh #ph container.

Comment: everything "outside" of <p></p> but still in the document. Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: See my updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dineshswami/YpYWY/3/ in this <p></p> trips and rest the html elements remain same as you want. Still you want any thing else you can ask.